# Will Karlov get multiple +1/+1 counters with Soul Warden when multiple tokens are created simultaneously?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When I have [Karlov of the Ghost Council](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karlov%20of%20the%20Ghost%20Council) and [Soul Warden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20Warden) on the battlefield and I cast something like [Lingering Souls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lingering%20Souls), does Karlov get two +1/+1 counters twice since two spirits enter the battlefield or only once since I cast Lingering Souls once?

The same thing applies to beautiful cards such as [Conqueror's Pledge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Conqueror%27s%20Pledge) - does Karlov get two +1/+1 counters six times or only once?

Comment: By the way: there are no +2/+2 counters involved in this situation. Only +1/+1 counters. (+2/+2 counters are only used on a few very old cards.)

Answer (score 7):

Soul Warden's ability reads:

> Whenever another creature enters the battlefield, you gain 1 life.

When Lingering Souls resolves, there are two separate instances of "another creature" entering the battlefield, and so the ability triggers twice, and you gain 1 life twice in two separate events.  Thus, Karlov's ability will trigger twice, and he will gain four +1/+1 counters.  Likewise, using Conqueror's Pledge instead will net you 6 life and twelve counters.

Compare rule 603.2c and its example:

> 603.2c An ability triggers only once each time its trigger event occurs. However, it can trigger repeatedly if one event contains multiple occurrences. See also rule 509.4.
>
> Example: A permanent has an ability whose trigger condition reads, “Whenever a land is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, . . . .” If someone casts a spell that destroys all lands, the ability will trigger once for each land put into the graveyard during the spell’s resolution.