# Karlov of the Ghost Council and multiple counters

Tags: magic-the-gathering

when I have [Karlov of the Ghost Council](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karlov%20of%20the%20Ghost%20Council) and [Righteous Cause](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Righteous%20Cause) on the battlefield and I attack with three creatures, does Karlos get six +1/+1 counters or only two counters since the creatures attack simultaneously?

Not sure whether the word "whenever" triggers for each creature or whether the attack counts as one trigger.

Thank you again!

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a duplicate of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/will-karlov-soul-warden-get-multiple-1-1-counters-when-multiple-tokens-are-cr or not...

Comment: @GendoIkari I think it's not because this question is essentially "how many attacking creature triggers do I get from combat", while the other is "how many ETB triggers do I get from multiple creatures entering at the same time". The questions just happen to involve similar setups, cards-wise.

Answer (score 5):

Karlov will get 6 +1/+1 counters with Righteous Cause. This is because the trigger says *"Whenever a creature attacks"*, so it triggers for each creature. If however it had been worded like [Path of Bravery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Path%20of%20Bravery), which says *"Whenever one or more creatures you control attack"*, that would only be one instance of life gain and thus only 2 +1/+1 counters.